# Convergence of power series by comparison test with geometric series.

Tags: analysis

Let $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_nz^n$ be a power series, such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_nz_0^n < \infty$. Thus $a_nz_0^n \rightarrow 0$.

(As I understand) the author caps $\left|\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_nz^n\right| = \left|\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_nz_0^n \left(\frac{z^n}{z_0^n}\right)\right| ≤ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left|\frac{z}{z_0}\right|^n$ for all $z < z_0$.

All I know at this point is that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\left|a_nz_0^n\right| < 1$ for all $n>N$.

How can I safely apply the direct comparison test for series convergence?

My idea is to look at the finite number of first summands separately, then compare to the rest of the geometric series.

Thx!

Comment: Your idea is correct. On the other hand, in the study of the convergence of a series you can always forget a finite number of terms.

Comment: So therefore, the second line of my problem is not universally correct. It will be true again if my set is all natural numbers greater than N.

Comment: The second line should by something like: $|a_n z^n| \leq \cdots \leq |z/z_0|^n$ for $n$ large enough, hence the series is absolutely convergent by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n{z_0}^n$ converges, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n{z_0}^n=0$ and therefore the sequence $\left(a_n{z_0}^n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded. Let $M$ be an upper bound of $\left(\lvert a_n{z_0}^n\rvert\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Then, if $|z|<|z_0|$,\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lvert a_nz^n\rvert&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lvert a_n{z_0}^n\right\rvert.\left\lvert\frac z{z_0}\right\rvert^n\\&\leqslant M\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lvert\frac z{z_0}\right\rvert^n.\end{align}Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake in my problem. [Absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) is convergence of the absolute values of the summands of the series.